# modrewrite website with slash in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, slash

How can I translate an URL like:
http://localhost/mySite/?link=OFFERS&sublink=ARTICLE&subsublink=DETAIL

to:
http://localhost/mySite/OFFERS/ARTICLE/DETAIL

if one parameter is empty it should still work like this:
localhost/mySite/?link=OFFERS&sublink=ARTICLE
localhost/mySite/OFFERS/ARTICLE

Extra problem: There is an enter page under index.php and the rewrite should work with index2.php. Best would be if it would work under localhost and on live system without changes.

Currently I'm using: RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ index2.php?link=$1 [L]
But that only works for one parameter and I couldn't improve this code for ages ^^

Comment: What do you mean by enter page? Do you mean enter site /leave site?

Comment: just that the redirect is not for the index.php -> not just for /?link=asdf.
but for /index2.php?link=asdf

index.php is just a welcome page with some internal links

Comment: I still do not get it. Do you mean you want to redirect `index.php/?link=asdf` or `/?link=asdf`  to `/index2.php?link=asdf` ?

Comment: with modrewrite you redirect to a site and give this site parameters in a recogniseable way. the target site here should be index2.php. usally it's a redirect from localhost/mysite/link to localhost/mysite/?link=asdf. but i want it to localhost/mysite/index2.php?link=asdf.
hope that helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)(/([^/.]+))?(/([^/.]+))?$ index2.php?link=$1&sublink=$3&subsublink=$5 [L,QSA]
```

Note that `localhost/mySite/OFFERS/ARTICLE` links to `localhost/mySite/?link=OFFERS&sublink=ARTICLE&sussublink=` and not `localhost/mySite/?link=OFFERS&sublink=ARTICLE`. 
Should not be a big issue, but make sure the PHP code doesn't us `isset($_GET['subsublink'])`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your htaccess file in the `mysite`directory of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mysite/

# rewrite http://localhost/mySite/OFFERS/ARTICLE/DETAIL to
# http://localhost/mySite/?link=OFFERS&sublink=ARTICLE&subsublink=DETAIL
#assumes that index2.php is in the root directory of site
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9])+/([-a-zA-Z0-9])+/([-a-zA-Z0-9])+ index2.php?link=$1&sublink=$2&subsublink=$3 [NC,L]

#redirect index to index2
#if you do not want to redirect, just server rewrite, remove the R=301 below
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ index2.php [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: i tried to get this code to work but only get an 404 error... index, index2 and .htaccess files are in xampp/htdocs/mysite/

Comment: @yourmother ok edited to reflect that everything is in `mysite` directory.

Comment: 404 error on localhost/mysite/OFFERS. if i modify the code to fit only 1 parameter not three then site is displayed but looks horribly (image pathes and file pathes don't seem to work correctly)